# ruby on rails logic for a partial in a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, partial-views

I have a sidebar that is going to have some logic in it, similar to how a view talks to a controller. Where do I put the logic in for the partial? Do I create a new controller for the layout and put it in there?

The layout is for logged in users, like a dashboard.
The dashboard is going to have a sidebar that shows the same dynamic content on every page.
Since it's being shown on every page I want to put it in a partial.

I'm just confused on where to put the find's and all that information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way to do this, but if it's on most or all pages you could create a [before_filter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) on your ApplicationController. You'll have to call `skip_before_filter` on the controllers/actions that don't need the data.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :load_sidebar_data

protected
  def load_sidebar_data

  end
end
```

If you don't need it on most pages you'd still put the method in the ApplicationController, you'd just add the before filter where you need it.

Comment: Andy, you've been a huge help to me these past two days! Thanks!

Comment: I have a sidebar which is the same on all pages except the homepage, and I'm using this code the grab the required data - now I'm wondering where is the correct place to put the actual view script code?

Answer (score 1):

Put the partial in the layouts folder. The name of the file should start with an underscore For example, "_mypartial.html.erb".

Then, in your views, use the following code to include the partial

"mypartial" %>

Note that you do not include the underscore in the embedded ruby code when specifying which partial to render.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Cells (view components for Rails):  http://cells.rubyforge.org/